# Reload best weights from Tensorflow Keras Checkpoints

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Is there a way to reload the weights from a certain epoch or the best weights from the model checkpoint files created by `ModelCheckpoint` once the training is over?

I have trained that trained for 10 epochs and created a checkpoint that only saved weights after each epoch. The final epoch's **val_categorical_accuracy** is a bit lower than epoch no. 5. I know I should have set `save_best_only=True` but I missed that.

- So now, is there a way to get the weights from the best epoch or the epoch number 5?
- Also, does `ModelCheckpoint` overwrites weights after each epoch in
  the checkpoint file?

What are my options here? Thanks for your help in advance.

Below is my implementation:

```
checkpoint_path = 'saved_model/cp.ckpt'
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
print(checkpoint_dir)

lstm_model.fit(X_train_seq_pad, y_train_cat,
               epochs=100,
               validation_data=(X_val_seq_pad, y_val_cat),
               callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3),
                          callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                    save_weights_only=True,
                                                    verbose=1)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `filepath` doesn't contain formatting options like `{epoch}` then `filepath` will be **overwritten** by each new better model. In your case, that's why you can't get the weight at a specific epoch (e.g epoch 5).

---

Your option here, however, is to choose the formatting option in the `ModelCheckpoint` callback during training time. Such as

```
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                     filepath='model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.4f}.h5', 
                     save_freq='epoch', verbose=1, monitor='val_loss', 
                     save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=False
                 )
```

This will save the model weight (in `.h5` format) at each epoch, in a different but convenient way. Additionally, if we choose `save_best_only` to `True`, it will save best weights in the same way.

---

**Code Example**

Here is one **end-to-end** working example for reference. We will save model weights at each epoch in a convenient way with a formatting option that we will define the `filepath` parameter as follows:

```
img = tf.random.normal([20, 32], 0, 1, tf.float32)
tar = np.random.randint(2, size=(20, 1))

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim = 32, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

callback_list = [
       tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            filepath='model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.4f}.h5', 
            save_freq='epoch', verbose=1, monitor='val_loss', 
            save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=False
       )         
]
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(img, tar, epochs=5, verbose=2, validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=callback_list)
```

It will save the model weight at each epoch. And I will find every weight in my local disk.

```
# model.epoch_number_score.h5
model.01-0.8022.h5
model.02-0.8014.h5
model.03-0.8005.h5
model.04-0.7997.h5
model.05-0.7989.h5
```

However, note that I used `save_best_only = False`, but If we set it to `True`, you then only get the best weight in the same way. Something like this:

```
# model.epoch_number_score.h5
model.01-0.8022.h5
model.03-0.8005.h5
model.05-0.7989.h5
```

Comment: Hey, Thank a lot for the crisp explanation. Yes, I realized that `ModelCheckpoint` will overwrite weights after reading the doc so providing a naming schema is a good way to side step it and preserve the history of trained weights. This was very helpful and I liked the naming schema you have suggested here.